# How to scale down an extrusion/hole in mesh?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, edit-mode

So I created some mesh stuff for Second Life.

[image: Stronk]

The biggest plate fits around the barbell fine, but I have an issue with the smaller ones where the size of the hole is too small because the circumference of the plate also becomes smaller.

I tried to scale the inner ring outward on the X and Y axis (Shift+Z).

[image]

If I scaled it inward I could see the effect I wanted, except I wanted the hole to become bigger, however the second image shows how that turned out.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you have 'Limit Selection to Visible' enabled, you might not have all the relevant verts selected.

[image]

The selected part seems to be unconnected to the rest of the mesh. 
It also looks like you have another object inside the disc which probably doesn't belong in there.

Ideally your mesh should have only one closed surface and, without sacrificing shape, as little faces as possible if it's for 2nd life.

[image]